# Why do union types break like this?

Tags: typescript, types, union-types, type-alias

When using a type alias, typescript complains about usage of a property that exists in one the types, even after explicitly stating which type is in use.
This doesn't break when calling a function on it.
Why is this the case?

For example:

```js
interface I1{
    type: "1"
    commonProp: any
    uniqueFor1: any
}
interface I2{
    type: "2"
    commonProp: any
    uniqueFor2: any
}
interface I3{
    type: "3"
    commonProp: any
    uniqueFor3: any
}

type typeX = (I1 | I2 | I3)

let somevar = {} as typeX
somevar.type = "1"
```

Doing this next will break everything:

```js
somevar.uniqueFor1 = " i am 1"
```

... but doing this works?

```js
function test(x: typeX) {
    
    switch (x.type) {
        case "1":
            x.uniqueFor1 = "i am 1"
            break;
        case "2":
            x.uniqueFor2 = "i am 2"
            break;
        case "3":
            x.uniqueFor3 = "i am 2"
            break;
    }    
}

test(somevar)
```

I am so confused.
EDIT:
There were issues in the original code.
I fixed them.
The problem still exists.

Comment: If I give you a banana or a watermelon, do you peal it or slice it in order to eat it? You don't know which one it is. Would you agree that it doesn't make sense to do either, if you don't even know what manner of fruit you have? Because that's what happens when it "breaks". You have no idea which type you have but you try to treat it as a specific one.

Comment: `{} as x` is a typo, yes?  Please make sure your code is a [mre] that demonstrates what you are talking about without unrelated issues.

Comment: @VLAZ I would agree, but I set the type immediately after initialization.

Comment: @AKam to the union type. The one that is not clear which of the three objects you have. So, you either have a banana or watermelon.

Comment: @VLAZ at that point in the code, I have already declared the type, implicitly anyways. Is this a native limitation of typescript?

Comment: The type is the union. If you try to set the `type` property, then do you really believe that if you had `somevar = { type: "1", commonProp: "hello, uniqueFor1: "this is 1 }` that the operation `somevar.type = "3"` is correct? I think you'd agree it isn't. Then why should TS think otherwise?

Comment: @VLAZ Apologies for the issue. However, even after correcting, the problem still exists. Seriously, try it.

Comment: I think what you expect to happen is for typescript to 'understand' that you mean `somevar` to have type `I3` because you set `type = 3`. One way to explain the breakage might be "typescript isn't smart enough" :-) ... however, when TS does infer something in a "smart" way ... we want it to be right. In this case, it would be wrong! The only reason it accepts setting `type` to `3` is because you told it it has union type `typeX`, by casting it. But that is false ... it's lacking properties.

Comment: One other often-stated fact is that Typescript doesn't play nice with mutability. Perhaps that's why it has no trouble with your function, but it can't make much out an _assignment_.

Comment: @AKam *again* chainging `type` to `3` when you have `I1` is wrong. Same if it is `I2`. And `typeX` can be either of them or `I3`. There is only one in three chance that assignment should be allowed. Remember that TS *does not know* whether it has I1 or I2 or I3. Setting a property should thus be valid for *all* of them in order to be allowed. It's not valid for all of them. It is not allowed. *Again* if you have an unknown fruit given to you, you cannot just decide to treat it as a specific one. If you start peeling a fruit and it was a watermelon, it doesn't turn into a banana.